# Vibration in 2016 Toyota Sequoia Platinum 4X4

Tags: toyota, vibration, sequoia

I have 2016 Toyota Sequoia Platinum 4x4, never off road- vibrates at lower speeds. Usually starts to occur at lower speeds, 35-45mph, city streets. The day we purchased and picked up, it vibrated so bad on test drive at 30-40 mph they took back in for service -said was out of balance and replaced all four tires. Since then - 2 years now, 32,660 miles, it continues to vibrate. Every maintenance visit to dealership, I have to balance and align. I replaced all four tires with Michelin about four months ago bc they said the tires (the new ones they had put on at purchase two years ago) were bad. Vibration comes back about three weeks after service visits. I feel it throughout my legs, hands, feet... so I’m not sure where it’s coming from.  I can't think of what they would be resetting at service visit that would fix the vibration that would then come back several week later. But it seems the wheels are pulling out of balance/alignment each time. Driving regular roads around town should not throw my SUV out of alignment/balance every 3 months. Any ideas??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you noticed if the vibration occurs at 35 mph when coasting down a hill ( no load and engine slowing you down)?

Comment: I'm not in an area with a lot of hills so from what I could tell on small "hills" I'd say yes, it seems to still vibrate coasting at 35